# Webpack watch true only works on package.json, not on all files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have my webpack watch all my files using `watch: true` in *webpack.config.js*.

I run webpack using `npm run build` through this code in *package.json*:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

Now when I use `npm run build`, it only compiles every time I save *package.json*. How do I change it so that it compiles every time I save a file in all of my folders?

**Full code**

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "testproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "code.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Figma",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@figma/plugin-typings": "*",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-inline-source-plugin": "0.0.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "figma-plugin-ds": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },

  mode: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',

  devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',

  entry: {
    ui: './src/ui.tsx',
    code: './src/code.ts',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        use: 'ts-loader', 
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },

      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      { 
        test: /\.svg/,
        type: 'asset/inline'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: { extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'] },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'global': {}
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: "body",
      template: './src/ui.html',
      filename: 'ui.html',
      chunks: ['ui']
    }),
    new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/ui/]),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, add `cache: false` in the HTMLWebpackPlugin object argument in *webpack.config.js*:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'global': {}
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: "body",
      template: './src/ui.html',
      filename: 'ui.html',
      chunks: ['ui'],
      cache: false // Add this line
    }),
    new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/ui/]),
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command in your package.json

```
webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It shows in the terminal that I have compiled it successfully, but it only truly compiles after saving *package.json*.

Comment: Try removing options watch and watchOptions in your webpack.config.js

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing still changes.